# creating private registry, id and password with -Bbn option

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Any one knows what does Bbn stands for in the below command

I am aware that,If the bbn option is not provided its not possible to write in the htpasswd file,but what is the meaning of it

```
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn testuser password > auth/htpasswd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html):

> `-B`  Use bcrypt encryption for passwords. This is currently considered to be very secure.
>
> `-b`  Use batch mode; i.e., get the password from the command line rather than prompting for it. This option should be used with extreme care, since the password is clearly visible on the command line. For script use see the -i option. Available in 2.4.4 and later.
>
> `-n`  Display the results on standard output rather than updating a file. This is useful for generating password records acceptable to Apache for inclusion in non-text data stores. This option changes the syntax of the command line, since the passwdfile argument (usually the first one) is omitted. It cannot be combined with the -c option.